# How to install python packages in linux locally from git?

Tags: python

so I do my `git clone` and change into that directory.
there I usually just do `python setup.py install --prefix=$HOME/.local` or something similar, whatever the README says
this results in installation of other python packages I already have installed.

the problem then is when I try to start such a program I get lots of `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named`  and the name of such additionally installed module. so on commandline I must write `PYTHONPATH=/usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages` in order to use the packages installed by the system. how do I get the same effect without setting this environment variable? how must I change the installed bin program to provide everything?

Answer (score -1):

concrete example: I'm on gentoo and strangely python3.11 is the default. also, I'm not using pip. and I tried

```
git clone git@github.com:kanzure/pdfparanoia.git
cd pdfparanoia/
python setup.py install --prefix=$HOME/.local/
```

now to make things work I edit $HOME/.local/bin/pdfparanoia:

```
#!/usr/lib/python-exec/python3.11/python
# EASY-INSTALL-SCRIPT: 'pdfparanoia==0.0.17','pdfparanoia'
import sys
sys.path.insert(1,'/usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages')
__requires__ = 'pdfparanoia==0.0.17'
__import__('pkg_resources').run_script('pdfparanoia==0.0.17', 'pdfparanoia')
```

i.e. I added `import sys` and insert the path.
I tested printing `sys.path` and it seems the required directory is the last entry, whereas with PYTHONPATH it becomes the 2nd, so that's where I inserted it at. this solves dependencies by installing them systemwide wherever possible.

Comment: Move this comment to question please (you can edit your posts)

Comment: @LinDu how is this not an answer to the question?